# get entries within a paragraph using sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed

I've a file as follows:

```
[para1]
abc-1-10 interpreter=/bin/sed
abc-1-11 interpreter=/bin/sed
[para2]
abc-2-100 interpreter=/bin/sed
abc-2-205 interpreter=/bin/sed
abc-2-206 interpreter=/bin/sed
[para3]
abc-3-15 interpreter=/bin/sed
abc-3-18 interpreter=/bin/sed
```

I need each para written to a separate file i.e. the line [para1] and the two entries i.e. abc-1-10 and abc-1-11

I tried

```
awk -v Var="\[para" '$1~Var{p=1}/^$/{p=0}p /tmp/filename
```

which gives an error as: `awk:warning: escape sequence '\[' treated as plain '['`

I also tried `awk -v Var="para" '$1~Var{p=1}/^$/{p=0}p /tmp/filename` and it prints the whole file!!. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`

```
$ awk '/^\[para/ {close(para);para="file"++c".txt"}{print > para}' input_file
$ head file*.txt
==> file1.txt <==
[para1]
abc-1-10 interpreter=/bin/sed
abc-1-11 interpreter=/bin/sed

==> file2.txt <==
[para2]
abc-2-100 interpreter=/bin/sed
abc-2-205 interpreter=/bin/sed
abc-2-206 interpreter=/bin/sed

==> file3.txt <==
[para3]
abc-3-15 interpreter=/bin/sed
abc-3-18 interpreter=/bin/sed
```

Comment: The solution works!!. At times the first line could be para20, is it possible to name the file as para20 instead of file1

Comment: @Aires69 Sure, use `awk -F'[][]' '/^\[para/ {close(para);para=$2".txt"}{print > para}' input_file`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU csplit):

```
csplit -q -f file -b %d.txt inputFile '/^\[/' '{*}' && rm file0.txt
```

Quiet, prefix of `file`, suffix of `n.txt` and remove the first empty file.